# Add text to vector image and export to JSON

Tags: qgis, geojson, labeling, topojson

I have a map created with QGIS. I am able to export it to geojson.
However when I test with mapshaper.org, all the "label" disappear. I understand the "labels" are stored in JSON attribute but my requirement is to show the "labels" (the location names) directly on the vector image.

Is it possible to use QGIS or any other method to add "location names"?

P.S. I need to import the JSON to Power BI which do not support displaying attributes on top of each Polygon.

Comment: Power BI will allow you to display the value of whatever is allocated to the *Location* field

Comment: create a field called location and calculate the field to be the label attribute.

Comment: That seems to be the only workaround https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZOanVP1PS0. Write mail to your Power BI support and make a feature request.